# Perl convert time in localtime format to YYYYMMDD

Tags: perl, time, posix, strftime, localtime

I have a string containing a date with this format

```
my $time = 'Fri Jan  8 14:24:27 2016';
```

And i want to convert it to YYYYMMDD.
I tried a couple of options such as :

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
print strftime("%Y%m%d", $time);
```

But it won't work.
Tried `localtime($time)` as well as many others but it won't work.

I guess i need to convert it to an intermediary format ?

Note : i need to use strftime/POSIX as i can't call other modules for many reasons. (no Date::Time etc.)

thanks in advance,

Comment: `strftime` converts a unix epoch timestamp (number of non-leap seconds since the start of 1970, UTC+0) to string. You need to first convert the input string to an epoch timestamp before you can use `strftime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece), part of the Perl core since 2007:

```perl
use Time::Piece;

my $time = 'Fri Jan  8 14:24:27 2016';
say Time::Piece->strptime($time, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')->ymd("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `POSIX::strftime()` incorrectly. It's always a good idea to check [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html), which says this:

> ```
> strftime
> ```
>
> Convert date and time information to string. Returns the string.
>
> Synopsis:
>
> ```
> strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1)
> ```
>
> The month (`mon`), weekday (`wday`), and yearday (`yday`) begin at zero, i.e., January is 0, not 1; Sunday is 0, not 1; January 1st is 0, not 1. The year (year ) is given in years since 1900, i.e., the year 1995 is 95; the year 2001 is 101. Consult your system's `strftime()` manpage for details about these and the other arguments.

So passing it a string containing a random(ish) representation of a datetime was slightly optimistic.

You need to parse your string and extract the bits that you need to pass to `strftime()`. As you've already be shown, the Modern Perl way to do that is to use a module like Time::Piece. But it's perfectly possible to do it with standard Perl too.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $time = 'Fri Jan  8 14:24:27 2016';

my ($day, $mon, $date, $hr, $min, $sec, $year) = split /[\s:]+/, $time;

my %months = (
  Jan => 0, Feb => 1, Mar => 2, Apr => 3,
  May => 4, Jun => 5, Jul => 6, Aug => 7,
  Sep => 8, Oct => 9, Nov => 10, Dec => 11,
);

$time = strftime('%Y%m%d',
                 $sec, $min, $hr, $date, $months{$mon}, $year - 1900);

say $time;
```

But don't do that. Use a module.